# Cannot use "a" (type string) as type in array element in go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm pretty new to Golang and I have an issue with adding items to Array.

I use this link as a reference [golang-book](http://www.golang-book.com/6/index.htm#section1).

I have this struct:

```
package models

type FileMD struct {
    fileName string
    fileSize int
}
```

I tried to do it both ways but I failed.

```
fileList := [...]models.FileMD{"a", 1: "b", 2}
var fileList [...]models.FileMD
fileList[0] = "a", 1
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you are looking for:

```
fileList[0] = FileMD{"a", 1}
```

Or maybe:

```
fileList := []FileMD{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
```

Comment: the second option will give me this error
 implicit assignment of unexported field 'fileName' in models.FileMD literal

Comment: I tried the second option in the same file when the struct is and it works 
but in another file it didnt

Comment: @MIkCode Change `fileName` to `FileName` to make "exported".

Comment: that's perfect  i forgot the capital field name thing

Answer (score 4):

First you need to decide if you want an [array](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) or a [slice](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types).

Once you decided, you have basically 2 options:

(Try the complete application on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/AKF4G-ogRp).)

#### 1) With a literal:

Initialize your array/slice with a [Composite literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) (either an array or slice literal) and you're done.

Arrays:

```
fileArr10 := [2]FileMD{FileMD{"first", 1}, FileMD{"second", 2}}
// Or short:
fileArr11 := [2]FileMD{{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}}
// With length auto-computed:
fileArr20 := [...]FileMD{FileMD{"first", 1}, FileMD{"second", 2}}
// Or short:
fileArr21 := [...]FileMD{{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}}
```

Slices (note the only difference between array and slice literals is that length is not specified):

```
fileSl10 := []FileMD{FileMD{"first", 1}, FileMD{"second", 2}}
// Or short:
fileSl11 := []FileMD{{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}}
```

#### 2) New, initialized array/slice and filling it:

Create a new, initialized array/slice and fill it by assiging values to its elements.

Array:

```
fileArr := [2]FileMD{}
fileArr[0] = FileMD{"first", 1}
fileArr[1] = FileMD{"second", 2}
```

Slice: (you can create slices with the built-in function [`make`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels))

```
fileSl := make([]FileMD, 2)
fileSl[0] = FileMD{"first", 1}
fileSl[1] = FileMD{"second", 2}
```

#### Final Note

Your struct `FileMD` is part of a package and it contains unexported fields (fields whose name start with lowercased letters).

Unexported fields are not accessible from outside of the package. This also means that when you create a value of such struct, you cannot specify the initial values of unexported fields.

So if you try to create a value of `FileMD` from outside of package `models`, you can only create zero-valued `FileMD`s like this: `FileMD{}`. Make your fields exported and then you can specify the initial values for the file name and size:

```
type FileMD struct {
    FileName string
    FileSize int
}

// Now FileMD{"first", 1} is valid outside of package models
```